# Loading image in view takes appx 10-20 seconds on IPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have created a app which pick image from Camera and on didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo pass this to another view and load this view. I think code is okay but it takes appx 15-20 seconds to display second view. So please let me know how can I fix this loading issue.

My code block is :

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(switchToSecondView:) toTarget:self withObject:info];
}

-(void) switchToSecondView:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info
              objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    secController =[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secController.myimage = image;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.navController pushViewController:secController animated:NO];
}
```

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Comment: Why are you using `detachNewThreadSelector` at picker delegate ?

Comment: never do UI functionality in other threads rather than main thread

Comment: To improve performance, i.e. when we click on camera to capture image, camera button get stuck, not responsive for 3-4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

UiKit is [overwhelmingly] safe to use on the main thread only. Your work in `switchToSecindView:` is happening on a background thread. Behaviour is therefore undefined.

Likely what's happening is that UIKit is failing to notice your changes until it happens to be doing some other processing.